# Custom user preferences storage

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

I’m creating a new add-on that will include some user preferences.
Let’s say each user can select multiple categories from a list of all content categories.

My goals are:

- the users preferences must be persistent (maybe OK to have them still here if I reinstall the add-on)
- the register and personal preferences pages to remain the same. I will have a custom view - form to update the preferences related to this add-on.
- easy to index the values in a custom catalog. The catalog will be used to search users interested in a subject (Example: my_custom_catalog.query(subject=“Education”) -> list of brains containing users data subscribed to “Education” topic). The catalog is removed on uninstall and updated when a user changes his preferences.

Can you recommend the best way to store this data? Can I use memberdata without changes in register and personal default forms? Or better to use persistent objects (import persistent)? (Any example very appreciated.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `profiles/default/memberdata_properties.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<object name="portal_memberdata">
  <property name="custom_topics" type="lines"></property>
</object>
```

You will create an upgrade step to import `memberdata-properties`.

Then use:

```
user = api.user.get(user_id)
user.getProperty("custom_topics")
```

to get the values and

```
user.setMemberProperties({'custom_topics':list_of_selected_topics})
```

to update them.

These values remain stored when the catalog is removed / add-on is uninstalled.
Also no changes in register page and personal preferences form, only if you want to (by extending them).

Comment: user.setMemberProperties({'custom_topics':list_of_selected_topics}) to be used instead of user.setProperties(custom_topics=list_of_selected_topics) - this one seems to save the values for the current logged in user all the time.